# Can not create NSError: unrecognized selector

Tags: initialization, objective-c-category, unrecognized-selector, nserror

I am trying to create a NSError category to make pre-defined errors based upon status codes. However, any time that I try to create a NSError from my category, I get a

```
+[NSError errorWithDomain:code:userInfo:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x2b2b20
```

I have also tried calling the instance version of the NSError Initializer but this has the same result.

```
+(NSError*)errorOfType:(ErrorType)errorType inClassNamed:(NSString*)_nsClassName andMessage:(NSString*)_nsMessage
{
    return [[[self class] alloc]initWithType:errorType inClassNamed: _nsClassName andMessage:_nsMessage];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - Init

-(id)initWithType:(ErrorType)errorType inClassNamed:(NSString*)_nsClassName andMessage:(NSString*)_nsMessage
{
    NSInteger _nCode = [self codeFromErrorType:errorType];
    NSDictionary *_nsUserInfo = [self localizedDescriptionForErrorType:errorType andMessage:_nsMessage];

    NSLog(@"Why Does this fail? Is this Nil? %@, \n%i, \n%@", _nsClassName, _nCode, _nsUserInfo);

    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(initWithDomain:code:userInfo:)]) {
        if (self = [self initWithDomain:_nsClassName code:_nCode userInfo:_nsUserInfo]){

        }
    }else{
        NSLog(@"NSERROR Did not create!!!");
    }

    return self;
}
```

When I run this code calling the static method, The output is:

```
2013-05-10 17:46:18.851 BMPassSDK-DemoApp[99692:c07] Why Does this fail? Is this Nil? Domain, 
107, 
{
    NSLocalizedDescription = "A connection to the server could not be made. Please Try again later. ";
}
2013-05-10 17:46:18.851 BMPassSDK-DemoApp[99692:c07] NSERROR Did not create!!!
2013-05-10 17:46:18.852 BMPassSDK-DemoApp[99692:c07] +[NSError errorWithDomain:code:userInfo:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x2b2b20
(lldb) po 0x2b2b20
$0 = 2829088 NSError
(lldb)
```

Anyone have any suggestions on what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I first made this class it was a subclass of NSError. Later, when I tried to convert it from a subclass to category, I accidentally renamed my header file's base class to type NSObject instead of NSError. This is of course what was causing my issue because NSObjects do not respond to the selector `initWithDomain:code:userInfo`.

Anyways, thanks everyone for looking. Hope it helps someone else.